# Indented Numbers with 7 in enumerate when font paratype is used

Tags: formatting, enumerate

When I use paratype, numbers like 7, 17 and 27 are looking a bit weird: they are a bit too far right

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paratype}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{5}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\setcounter{enumi}{15}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\setcounter{enumi}{25}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

looks like this:

[image: indented 6,7,8,16,17,18,26,27,28]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks OK to me, however to see what is happening add `\showoutput` and you see

```
.......\OT1/PTSans-TLF/m/n/10 7
.......\kern-1.1
.......\OT1/PTSans-TLF/m/n/10 .
```

so the font specifies a kern between 7 and .

If you want to stop that you could add `\mbox{.}` rather than `.` in the label by adding

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi\noboundary\mbox{.}}


.......\OT1/PTSans-TLF/m/n/10 7
.......\hbox(1.00499+0.12)x1.35997
........\OT1/PTSans-TLF/m/n/10 .
```

Comment: wouldn't adding `{}` before the period also suppress the kern?

Comment: @barbarabeeton not in luatex and not in general in classic tex either, it would here as in this context there is no hyphenation but as noted in the texbook `{}` doesn't suppress kerns if the word is attempted for hyphenation and then re-constituted.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of the reconstitution problem.  but it's unlikely that *any* item label would ever be considered for hyphenation.  (even a `description` label -- although not for the same reason, and sometimes to my great distress.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton true but answers get used out of context and undoubtedly the font kern for `7.` is global so if you don't like it here you may not like it in other places as well so may as well suggest a method that works everywhere. (I thought that was `\mbox` but it has a boundary kern for `7` as well, so that caught me out, and I had to add `\noboundary`:-)

Comment: okay.  good explanation for \noboundary (which i didn't know about).  the thing i find objectionable about *this* instance of "7." is not the kerning per se (although in general i really don't like over-kerning), but the fact that with 2-digit numbers, the leading edges don't line up.  it wouldn't be so obvious, or obnoxious, at the end of a sentence, say "... in 2007."  (my pet kerning peeve is with periods following initials in bibliographies and the like, particularly "P." and other letters where the separation that should be present between adjacent initials totally disappears.)